# angularjs adding an option to 2 dropdown lists using array.push references same object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an array of persons like:

```
[
  {'name': 'Bob', 'age': 25, 
  'addresses': [
               {
                'city': 'San Franscisco', 'state': 'CA','streetline': 'One Drive',
                'selected': true
               },
               {
                'city': 'San Jose', 'state': 'CA', 'streetline': 'Two Drive',
                'selected': false}
               ]
               ]
  },
  {'name': 'Rob', 'age': 29, 
  'addresses': [
               {
                'city': 'Baltimore', 'state': 'MD', 'streetline': 'Three Drive', 
                'selected': false
               },
               {
                'city': 'Detroit', 'state': 'MI', 'streetline': 'Four Drive',
                'selected': true}
               }
               ]
  }
]
```

One of the external applications can add a new common address to each person by pushing a new address to each of persons objects.

The addresses are used to populate dropdown lists for each person. When the new address is added it shows up differently in each addresses array. When the new address is selected in the dropdown for either of the persons the selected flag for that address is set to true and for all other travelers it's set to false.

The problem is that if I select a different address for one traveler and the new address for the other traveler the new address in the first traveler references the new address in the second traveler. Because of which the selected flag is not what it should be. While debugging it shows up for traveler 2 as {'selected': true} and for traveler 1 as $ref [1][address] which is referencing traveler 2's selected address.

I don't know why that's happening.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The relevant part is the code where the issue seems to occur but it is not here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the problem happens at the point where you push the new options to the travelers. If you do it like this:

```
travellers[0].addresses.push(newAddress);
travellers[1].addresses.push(newAddress);
```

Both share a reference to the same address and the problem you describe may occur. You may use angulars `copy` method to prevent this from happening.

```
travellers[0].addresses.push(angular.copy(newAddress));
travellers[1].addresses.push(angular.copy(newAddress));
```

`angular.copy()` creates a deep copy of its argument so that both travellers addresses contain their own copy of the new address.

For more information see: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy